# What is the right syntax reading boolean value from firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im very new to firebase i dont know that much the syntax to use. Im creating a game that have a timer, the timer will start if my game reads in the firebase that the start_gameRef is `true`. The whole timer is completely working my main problem is reading the boolean value to firebase which is the trigger to start the game.

my firebase structure:

[image]

I know there is something wrong in this code below

```
var start_gameRef = firebase.database().ref().child("switch");
```

this is the whole function below

```js
function startGame(){
    var timeleft = 60;
    var start_gameRef = firebase.database().ref().child("switch");
    if (start_gameRef == true) {    
        var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1(){
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + 
            "&nbsp"+"seconds remaining";
            document.getElementById("gameStart").disabled = true;

            timeleft -= 1;
            if(timeleft <= 0){
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                document.getElementById("gameStart").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time is up!"
                declareWinner();
            }
        }, 1000);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the entire path to the node you want to read. So since `switch` is under players, it'll be at the very least `players/switch`. If `players` is directly under the root of your database, that is:

```
var start_gameRef = firebase.database().ref().child("playes/switch");
```

Or slightly shorter with the same result:

```
var start_gameRef = firebase.database().ref("playes/switch");
```

---

But this doesn't read anything from the database yet, it merely sets up a reference to that data in the cloud. To actually read the data you need to attach a listener with `on()` or `once()`:

```
var start_gameRef = firebase.database().ref("playes/switch");
start_gameRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    var value = snapshot.val();
    if (value == true) {    
        ...
```

Note that reading from the database is quite well covered in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) and in many tutorials out there, so I highly recommend studying those when you get stuck.

Comment: I think i did a wrong code to use because it only read once. When i change the value of switch it doesn't start in realtime.

Comment: I used `once()` in my answer, which only reads the value from the database once and stop listening after that. To keep listening for changes, use `on()`. See the docs I linked for details on both, but it'd be almost the same except: `start_gameRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {...`

Comment: I've already tried it the on() but it doesn't work it said. \Uncaught Error: Query.on failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects at least 2.
    at ua (validation.ts:48)
    at wf.yh.on (Query.ts:206)
    at startGame ((index):124)
    at (index):197

Comment: Check the comment I left again, as I changed more than just `once` to `on` there. And as said, the docs also contain the exact code you need for `on`.

Comment: Thank you! im very dumb i just change the once to on. I should change the whole line like you said.